# Use REFERENCES in Vertical Fragmentation table in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

First create the following tables in two different databases

```
Fragment1:
Employee(EID number(4)PRIMARY KEY, Name varchar2(20),Address varchar2(50));

Fragment2:
Employee(EID number(4),Dep_Id number(4),Mgr_Id REFERENCES Employee(EID),Salary number(6));
```

and then
Create a trigger to insert data into appropriate table.

I am not able to use REFERENCE Employee(EID) [of Fragment 1] in Mgr_Id

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot implement FK constraint over dblink. What you can do is to write a trigger mimicking the function of the FK constraint. Something like this:

First you need to create a dblink (eg. remote) to server2

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Example
  AFTER INSERT ON fagment1
    FOR EACH ROW
 DECLARE
    cuenta number;
 BEGIN

  select count(*) 
    into cuenta 
    from fagment2@Remote f2 
   where f2.EID = :new.EID 
     and rownum=1;

  IF cuenta = 0 then
    raise_application_error(-20001,'EID: '||:new.EID||'  not found');
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN --dblink down?
            raise_application_error(-20001,'EID: '||:new.EID||'  not found');

END;
```

Comment: both the tables are created in different databases... so the above code is not working.

Comment: can you tell me how the trigger will be?